# создание 256 одноцветных картинок из изображения 16х16

Tags: bash, imagemagick

используется termux на смартфоне, нужен bash скрипт.

ffmpeg создаёт изображение - палитру 16х16
нужно попиксельно проанализировать в ImageMagick эту палитру, затем для каждого пикселя создать картинку размером ну хоть те же 16х16 пикселей и заполнить её извлеченным цветом. Имя картинки координата_ргб.png

например у меня в палитре левый верхний пиксель чёрного цвета значит картинка должна быть залита чёрным цветом и иметь имя 01х01_000,000,000.png

последний пиксель в палитре белый, последняя картинка будет иметь имя
16х16_256,256,256.png

максимум что удалось найти - попиксельное сохранение в текстовый файл ргб цветов с картинки.

Предполагаю что есть два способа?

1. Из палитры извлекается координата и значение цвета и создаётся новое изображение с нужным именем и заливкой цветом.
2. Из палитры конвертируется часть изображения(пиксель) с нужным цветом в картинку нужного размера и с нужным именем.

Какой вариант эффективнее, и не будет ли второй вариант "грязнить" не знаю.

Comment: Разбить то не проблема: magick  palett.png -sample 1600%x1600% p16.png 
magick p16.png -crop 16x16  +repage  +adjoin  pic_%02d.png
а дальше уже в цикле for переименовывать.

Comment: спасибо. Расшифрую немного:
  
  
`magick "/storage/emulated/0/Download/palette.png" -sample 1600%x1600% "/storage/emulated/0/Download/p16.png"`
  
  
  потом   
  
  
  
`magick "/storage/emulated/0/Download/p16.png" -crop 16x16 +repage +adjoin "/storage/emulated/0/Download/pic_%03d.png"`
  
  
  
%02d изменено на %03d(у нас 256 цветов/пикселей/картинок).  Кстати одним for не получится, надо же в названии картинки её ргб цвет указать..